# How to grab piece of a string from a bigger string using regex or any method

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to extract a piece of string from a larger string.

**Example:**

```
String value;
...etc...
value = someMethod();

// Here value equals a large string text
value;
```

I want to extract a subset of this string which begins with "path=" and everything after it.

**Elaborated Example:**

if value equals:

> StartTopic topic=testParser, multiCopy=false, required=true,
>   all=false, path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2

I want only "path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2" so on and so forth.

How could I do this in Java?

This is what I currently have:

```
if(value.contains("path")) {
    String regexStr = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("regex.txt"));
    String escapedRegex = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(regexStr);
    System.out.println(value.replaceAll(escapedRegex), "$1");
}
```

This doesn't work! Just outputs the whole string again

**Contents of regex.txt:**

> /path=([^\,]+)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```java
String s = "if value=StartTopic topic=testParser, multiCopy=false, required=true, all=false, path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2";
String regex= "path=[^\\,]*";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
String regex = "(?<=path=)[^\\,]*";
```

insted, so you will get only `/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2` part.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function indexOf() to find the index of 'path='

Comment: This would only work with an expected length of string of text

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = "path=/Return/ReturnData/IRSW2";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf("path=") + 5));
```

Comment: OP clearly stated "regex or any method"